# How to query a property of an object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  a: { 
   b: 1,
   c: 3
  }
}
```

```
db.col.aggregate([{$match: {a: /* some condition about b or c */ }}])
// e.g.
db.col.aggregate([{$match: {a: {b: { $eq: 5 }}}}])
```

So the idea is to specify some condition about the property of a field that is an object.

I am aware of this syntax:

```
db.col.aggregate([{$match: {"a.b": /* some condition about b */ }}])
```

But that is not the goal. The goal is the first syntax.

Comment: why not use the path `a.b` or `a.c` ? If you dont know what names the field might have inside a document, you can use `$objectToArray` and then filter for example, but its not good idea to have unknown field names, maybe give an example of the problem you want to solve

Comment: Can you please provide a valid condition as example instead of "some condition about..."

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I added the example

Comment: What is the problem with syntax `"a.b": 5`?

Comment: my match conditions are generated by a function and there are many. So it seems more readable to group conditions about the property of an object field together into a hierarchy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query

```
db.col.aggregate([{$match: {a: {b: { $eq: 5 }}}}])
```

Does not mean select every document where element `b` of element `a` is 5, it means select every document where element `a` is exactly `{b: {$eq: 5}}` (verbatim, i.e., that will not match `{b: 5}`) see https://mongoplayground.net/p/8l0BTpdDHTp

The query

```
db.col.aggregate([{$match: {"a.b": {$eq: 5}}}])
```

will match documents where `a` is an object with a field `b` that equals 5, even if there are other fields.  See https://mongoplayground.net/p/mnZVGDaqYpz

If you need multiple criteria, you can list them separately at the top level like:

```
db.col.aggregate([{$match: {
                            "a.b": {$eq: 5},
                            "a.c": {$gte: 1}
                           }}])
```